# How to install java 8.0.232 Ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I need to install the 8.0.232 openjdk version. I am using sdkman and the result of `sdk list java` is:

```
 Java.net      |     | 15.ea.25     | open    |            | 15.ea.25-open       
               |     | 14.0.1       | open    |            | 14.0.1-open         
               |     | 13.0.2       | open    |            | 13.0.2-open         
               |     | 12.0.2       | open    |            | 12.0.2-open         
               |     | 11.0.7       | open    |            | 11.0.7-open         
               |     | 10.0.2       | open    |            | 10.0.2-open         
               |     | 9.0.4        | open    |            | 9.0.4-open          
               |     | 8.0.252      | open    |            | 8.0.252-open        
               | >>> | 8.0.242      | open    | local only | 8.0.242-open
```

How can I install the 8.0.232?

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 8.0.232

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openjdk-8-jdk for latest version with security fixes applied.

Comment: But as I said, I specifically need the 232 version

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/contrib_jdk8u-ci/releases/tag/jdk8u232-b09) contains the exact release that you want. Looks like the version you want is not in the ubuntu repo but in the centos' . But you can still download the source code and compile it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get the binary [OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_8u232b09.tar.gz](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u232-b09/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_8u232b09.tar.gz) from [Release OpenJDK 8u232 GA Release · AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries · GitHub](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases/tag/jdk8u232-b09). Or simply run

   ```bsh
   wget https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-upstream-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u232-b09/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_8u232b09.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the tarball and save the contents in `/usr/lib/jvm`. This the location where Ubuntu by default save JVMs. You can use other locations as well.

   ```bsh
   sudo tar -xvf OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_8u232b09.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
   ```
3. Install the alternatives for `java` and `javac`.

   ```bsh
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8u232-b09/bin/java 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8u232-b09/bin/javac 1
   ```
4. Configure the alternatives.

   ```bsh
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   sudo update-alternatives --config javac
   ```

   Choose the option number corresponding to `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8u232-b09/bin/java*`.
5. Verify the installation.

   ```bsh
   $ java -version
   openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
   ```